# how to scroll to the center position of the object

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uikit

Hi Im making a simple game with the basic `UIKit` stuff where there is an object that pops up on the screen.

I'm trying to make it so that every time the object pops up the screen will scroll to the object and center it on screen. Basically I have a `UIView` that has the objects that popup within it and that `UIView` is a subview of a `UIScrollView`. All of this is a subview of `self.view` of my `ViewController`. I'm using the `UIScrollview` to scroll through the contents of its subview with the objects in it. I'm not sure if a `UIScrollView` is the ideal option for what I want to do but I was looking for a way to scroll the position of the object and center it in the middle of the device. Ideally with animation.

If anyone knows of a method or maybe a formula that could help me out that would be awesome. Thanks in advance :D

Update:
I don't really have much code in regards to this except for adding the views within each other :

```
self.world =  [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, currentDeviceWidth*4, currentDeviceHeight*2.2)];
self.world.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];

_scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:[[self view] bounds]];
[_scrollView setContentSize:self.world.frame.size];

[_scrollView addSubview:self.world];
[[self view] addSubview:_scrollView];
```

but below is a simple image of what I want to accomplish. The arrows are just a representation of the possible scrolling direction.

Apple object is off the side of the screen Note: apple object is a subview of self.world and self.world is a subview of scrollview

[image: apple object is off the side of the screen Note: apple object is a subview of self.world and self.world is a subview of scrollview]

The finish look is where now the scrollview has scroll self.world to where the apple object is in the center of the screen

[image: The finish look is where now the scrollview has scroll self.world to where the apple object is in the center of the screen]

Just looking to basically accomplish how a user could manually scroll the object to the center but instead do it automatically without the use of a user's touch.

Comment: Try to make the question more specific. And maybe add some of your code so we all can see how to improve your solution. Image captures would be great too to show what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you may need `contentOffset` which is a property of `UIScrollView`. This property controls the position of the contentView. 
Now let's say, your apple is in the center of the self.world, then animated put it in the middle is like this:

```
    [UIView animateWithDuration: 0.5//you can put any float as you want
                     animations:^{self.world.contentOffset = CGPointMake((_scrollview.frame.size.width - self.world.frame.size.width) / 2, (_scrollview.frame.size.height - self.world.frame.size.height) / 2);
                    }];
```

If you put your apple in any other position, you should calculate the position yourself, and set the `contentOffset` to the right one. I think any position other than center is much complicated, you calculation should involve the position of the apple in the self.world view.

Comment: thanks i used the method you said and that definitely did what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try

```
[_scrollView scrollRectToVisible:newView.frame animated:(BOOL)animated]
```

What might be tricky about what you are trying to do is positioning views such that they are always within the coordinate system of the _scroll view, e.g. x >= middle of the view & y >= middle of the view.

Comment: so as far as newView does that mean i need to create a new view? or is that the object view(apple symbol in example picture)

Comment: It's the rect of the view you want to have centered.